# How do I check if a string contains both lowercase and uppercase letters in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, uppercase, lowercase

I want to write a function that checks if a string contains lowercase **and** uppercase letters. If both are present, it should return true, and if either are missing, it should return false.

```
function lowercaseUppercase (letterCase) {
  
  if (letterCase == letterCase.toUpperCase()) 
  {
  return true; 
} else {
  return false; 
};  
}

console.log(lowercaseUppercase("GGG"))
```

This will return `true` if I use uppercase letters, and `false` if I pass lowercase letters to this function. If I substitute `letterCase.toUpperCase()` for `letterCase.toLowerCase()`it works. I want the function to check both parameters are true.

Can I use the `&&` operator to check both?

```
function lowercaseUppercase (letterCase) {
  
  if (letterCase == letterCase.toUpperCase() &&
      letterCase == letterCase.toLowerCase()) 
  {
  return true; 
} else {
  return false; 
};  
}
```

This does not work and returns false for uppercase, lowercase, and a combination of both.

If both are present, it want it to return true, and if either are missing, it should return false.

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong? :)

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want a function that only returns true when the input has mixed cases (i.e. if entirely lowercase or entirely uppercase, return false). in that case, you could replace AND operator with OR operator, and swap your return statements.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could check with a regular expression and return `true` if both cases are `true`.

Methods:

- [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND)

```js
function allCases(string) {
    const
        upper = /[A-Z]/.test(string),
        lower = /[a-z]/.test(string);

    return upper && lower;
}

console.log(allCases('abc'));
console.log(allCases('ABC'));
console.log(allCases('abC'));
console.log(allCases('123'));
```

A different approach by itrating the string.

```js
function allCases(string) {
    let upper = false,
        lower = false;

    for (const character of string) {
        if (character.toUpperCase() === character.toLowerCase()) continue;
        upper ||= character === character.toUpperCase();
        lower ||= character === character.toLowerCase();
        if (upper && lower) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(allCases('abc'));
console.log(allCases('ABC'));
console.log(allCases('abC'));
console.log(allCases('123'));
```

Comment: regex is probably not something @OP knows

Answer (score 1):

The `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` functions operate on the entire string at once.

If you try this out on a js terminal you will see that:

```
"Hello World!".toUpperCase() === "HELLO WORLD!"
```

Based on your question, I think what you want is to check character by character.

You can use `Array.from` to convert the string into an array an then check if any character meets a given condition using the `Array.some` method:

```
const input = "Hello World!";
const containsUpperCase = Array.from(input).some((c) => c === c.toUpperCase());
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

(Edit) I realize the arrow function syntax might not be very beginner friendly so here is an alternative:

```
function charIsUppercase(c) {
    return c === c.toUpperCase();
}

const input = "Hello World!";
const containsUpperCase = Array.from(input).some(charIsUppercase);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing is just converting string to upper and lower case.
Here a one liner solution.

```js
const verifyString = (str)=> (/[a-z]/.test(str)) && (/[A-Z]/.test(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

`letterCase == letterCase.toUpperCase()` does not actually check that there are uppercase letters in the string, it checks that there are *no lowercase letters* in the string. Consequentially, your `&&` expression checks that there are neither lowercase nor uppercase letters in the string.

So for checking that there are both lowercase and uppercase letters, you'd need to do

```
function lowercaseUppercase (letterCase) {
  return !(letterCase == letterCase.toUpperCase() || letterCase == letterCase.toLowerCase());  
}
```

or

```
function lowercaseUppercase (letterCase) {
  return letterCase != letterCase.toUpperCase()  // has lowercase letters
      && letterCase != letterCase.toLowerCase(); // has uppercase letters
}
```